# what's wrong with my php syntax?

Tags: php, html, arrays, parsing

I'm trying to display products on my page I was hoping to store products and their attributes in a 2d array then include them on the page and display them. This way I could add products just by editing the 2d array.

here's my catalog.php

```
<?php
$varProduct = array
(
// title, style, price, number of xsmalls, number of small, number of medium, number of large, number of xl, number small picture path, medium picture path, large picture path, sale 

array("Title" , 10213 , 100, 0,0,1,1,0, "/womens/tops/s/2.png", "/womens/tops/s/2.jpg", "/womens/tops/s/2.jpg", 50  )
array("Title" , 10213 , 100, 0,0,1,1,0, "/womens/tops/s/2.png", "/womens/tops/s/2.jpg", "/womens/tops/s/2.jpg", 50  )

)
?>
```

I want to display the title index [0] the picture index [8] and the price index [2]

here's myPage.php

```
<h3 style="margin-bottom:20px; left:10px; position:relative;"> New Women's designs and colors </h2>


        <?php
        include("catalog.php");
        for($x =0; $x < count($varProduct); $x++ )
        {
        echo $varProdct[x][0];  
        }   

        ?>
```

I get an error on the page  ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'array' (T_ARRAY), expecting ')' in C:\wamp\www\sparta\WomensNewArrivalCatalog.php on line 7
Call Stack

how can I display what I need to display I don't see where my syntax is wrong.

edit: after adding the comma I get a

( ! ) Notice: Use of undefined constant x - assumed 'x' in C:\wamp\www\sparta\myPage.php on line 101
Call Stack

## Time    Memory  Function    Location

1   0.0000  144880  {main}( )   ..\myPage.php:0

Comment: Catalog.php, end of the first array. You're missing a comma...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing comma "," after first index of main array and a semicolon at the end of main array. 
Here how your code should look like:

```
$varProduct = array
(
   array("Title" , 10213 , 100, 0,0,1,1,0, "/womens/tops/s/2.png", "/womens/tops/s/2.jpg", "/womens/tops/s/2.jpg", 50  ),
   array("Title" , 10213 , 100, 0,0,1,1,0, "/womens/tops/s/2.png", "/womens/tops/s/2.jpg", "/womens/tops/s/2.jpg", 50  )

);
```

[edit]:
There is another syntax errors in your other myPage.php file as well. such as missing $ for variable x at echo statement.

Comment: okay but I then get a ( ! ) Notice: Use of undefined constant x - assumed 'x' in C:\wamp\www\sparta\ on line 101
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0000 144880 {main}( ) ..\.php:0
 error

Comment: thats because you have to use $ sign for variables in php. instead using "x"  use $x ..

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a comma after the first element of the array. Every element in the array should be separated by a comma. I would recommend using an IDE such as sublime text which has a plug in for checking syntax errors.